# Removing vertices and their attributes from a BufferGeometry in Three.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, graphics, three.js

I have a large Three.js `Points` (formerly `PointCloud`) object. It's essentially many different point cloud forms all put into a single `Points` object so I can render it efficiently with a single `BufferGeometry` in a WebGLRenderer.

My program is interactive, and a user can select a point cloud form, which disappears, to be replaced by a new point cloud. To do this, I loop through the ID number I've assigned to each vertex, looking for the vertices associated with the form the viewer selected. I then log the `startIndex` and `endIndex` for the form's vertices and slice that span of elements from each of the attribute arrays in the `BufferGeometry`. I then tag the attributes for an update to the graphics card.

I've validated that the index values are correct by first performing a simple color change before then proceeding to edit the arrays. Unfortunately, once I edit the arrays, the behavior is really erratic and the forms, which are arranged in a grid, appear to recede from the screen from left to right in a patchy manner. What I want to happen is that each form disappears as it is selected. Is the array of positions a fixed length once it is uploaded to the graphics card? Or is it dynamic? I've been puzzling over solutions to this for several days now.

The program is rather complex, so I've excerpted what I think are the problem areas below:

```
function extractFormFromTypedArray( startIndex, endIndex, itemSize, typedArray ) {
    // The startIndex and endIndex are the range of points to remove in order to delete the form the viewer has selected
    // startIndex is inclusive, end index in non-inclusive
    var deleteCount = (endIndex * itemSize) - (startIndex * itemSize);
    var regularArray = Array.from( typedArray );
    regularArray.splice( startIndex, deleteCount ); // regular array now contains only the unselected motifs' values
    var newEditedTypedArray =  new Float32Array( regularArray );
    return newEditedTypedArray;
}

function swapForm( formID ) {

    var targetFormIndexes = findForm( formID );

    var positionArray = gridOfForms.geometry.getAttribute( 'position' );
    positionArray.array = extractFormFromTypedArray( targetMotifIndexes.startIndex, targetMotifIndexes.endIndex, 3, positionArray.array );

    var attribute1Array = gridOfForms.geometry.getAttribute( 'attribute1' );
    attribute1Array.array = extractFormFromTypedArray( targetMotifIndexes.startIndex, targetMotifIndexes.endIndex, 1, attribute1Array.array );

    var attribute2Array = gridOfForms.geometry.getAttribute( 'attribute2' );
    attribute2Array.array = extractMotifFromTypedArray( targetMotifIndexes.startIndex, targetMotifIndexes.endIndex, 1, attribute2Array.array );

    gridOfForms.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
    gridOfForms.geometry.attributes.attribute1.needsUpdate = true;
    gridOfForms.geometry.attributes.attribute2.needsUpdate = true;
}
```

Three.js v74

Comment: You cannot resize buffers. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @WestLangley's comment I now know what's going on. The buffers are a fixed length once they are implemented, which means they can be updated with new values, but no more values can be added or deleted. According to the [link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates) he offered I do have an option to emulate buffer editing, which is likely what I will do:

> You can only update content of buffers, you cannot resize buffers
>   (this is very costly, basically equivalent to creating new geometry).
>
> You can emulate resizing by pre-allocating larger buffer and then
>   keeping unneeded vertices collapsed / hidden.
>
> Set flags only for attributes that you need to update, updates are
>   costly. Once buffers change, these flags reset automatically back to
>   false. You need to keep setting them to true if you wanna keep
>   updating buffers.

Thanks!!